# Pytest Version Conflict Error

Tags: python, debian, pytest

After update of Debian (Jessie), pytest doesn't work :

```
#py.test

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py.test", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pytest==2.4.2', 'console_scripts', 'py.test')())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 348, in      load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2311, in     load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2024, in load
    if require: self.require(env, installer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2037, in require
    working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 571, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (py 1.4.15 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('py>=1.4.17'))
```

How can I fix this error? Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` belong to python packages you installed with pip, easy_install or `python setup.py`. The system update probably messed up some dependencies. Does this work?

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo /usr/bin/pip install -U pytest
```

Comment: Cool, it works. Last Command has done the work. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Some instances might have more than one pytest running. 
Try:

```
sudo apt-get remove pytest
```

Then run your test again.