# Why tox faces Pytest Version Conflict?

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest, tox

I'm going to ask for help because the answers to very similar questions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475429/pytest-version-conflict-error), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475429/pytest-version-conflict-error) couldn't help me to solve the issue.

`tox` runs error-free in my local environment, but in [travis ci](https://travis-ci.org/p-alik/python-genieacs-nbi-client/builds/519378647#L435) with same versions of `tox`, `pytest`, etc it throws following exception:

```
pluggy.manager.PluginValidationError: Plugin 'removestalebytecode' could not be loaded: (pytest 4.4.0 (XXX/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pytest<3.10'))!
```

**Where comes** `pytest 4.4.0` **from?** 
`pytest --version` [shows](https://travis-ci.org/p-alik/python-genieacs-nbi-client/builds/519378647#L373) version `3.7.4`, which was explicitly installed by `pip install 'pytest~=3.7.0' --force-reinstall` [travis ci setup](https://github.com/p-alik/python-genieacs-nbi-client/blob/master/.travis.yml#L13).

Comment: Impossible to answer without a [mcve]. No idea what specifically you have on your system and what specifically you are running. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: https://travis-ci.org/p-alik/python-genieacs-nbi-client/builds/519378647#L390 : `py35 installed: <...> pytest==4.4.0` Tox creates an own Python installation separate from the system's, that complies to `tox.ini`.

Comment: As mentioned `tox` and `pytest` in [travis setup](https://github.com/p-alik/python-genieacs-nbi-client/blob/master/.travis.yml) are equal to [local environment](https://github.com/p-alik/python-genieacs-nbi-client/blob/master/default.nix)

Comment: You don't install `pytest` explicitly. My guess is that leads to different versions in a new vs existing environment.

Comment: But `pip install 'pytest~=3.7.0' --force-reinstall` is last install statement in [travis setup](https://github.com/p-alik/python-genieacs-nbi-client/blob/master/.travis.yml#L13)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658138/why-tox-faces-pytest-version-conflict?noredirect=1#comment98005779_55658138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Where comes pytest 4.4.0 from?**

`tox` installed it completely independently from `pip install 'pytest~=3.7.0' --force-reinstall`

It could be solve by sticking `tox` environment to particular `pytest` version in `tox.ini`

```
[py]
deps=
    pytest<3.10
    ...
```

It wouldn't solve the issue with

```
pluggy.manager.PluginValidationError: Plugin 'removestalebytecode' could not be loaded: (pytest 4.4.0 (XXX/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pytest<3.10'))!
```

because in current version 3.0.1 [pytest-remove-stale-bytecode](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-remove-stale-bytecode/) plug-in doesn't work with `py.test` 3.10.

**To solve the issue** `tox.ini` **should constrain version of** `pytest-remove-stale-bytecode`

```
[py]
deps=
    ...
    pytest-remove-stale-bytecode<3.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the instruction. But I need to move `pytest<3.10` and `pytest-remove-stale-bytecode<3.0.1` to `deps=` of `[testenv]` section to make it work.